# How to assign an incrementing values to a variable in optplanner?

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I am planning to use optplanner to optimize the server usage and if required add  additional hardware on demand.

My questions is: How to auto increment one variable if system is not able to find a optimal solution after a certain fixed time?

Comment: That relates to "overconstrained planning" which will be documented in the 6.3.0.Beta1 release.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it would work for your specific use case but you could define a [custom phase](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/6.2.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#customSolverPhase) where you modify your Problem Entity.

If you need to modify a Problem Fact then I would set a time on a thread separate from the one where you called solve(). Once the timer hits 0 you can introduce a [ProblemFactChange](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/6.2.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#problemFactChange) to the solver.

Comment: Thanks for the possible solution, but I am more looking for a feature supported by Optaplanner itself. e.g. Provide a possible range of available virtual machine on each computer, then solver solves for computer 1 - 2 virtual machine, Computer 2 - 1 virtual machine and so on.